# Differences Between GlassFish "ogs-3.1.2.2-windows.exe" and "ogs-3.1.2.2-windows-ml.exe" File

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

What's the differences between **GlassFish** *ogs-3.1.2.2-windows.exe* and *ogs-3.1.2.2-windows-**ml**.exe* [1] file?

[1] : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/ogs-3-1-1-downloads-439803.html

Answer (score 4):

The 'ml' suffix means 'multi-lingual'.

From the Glassfish web page:

> Multilingual support available for French, German, Spanish, Japanese,
>   Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese, and Korean.

Answer (score 3):

One with the *ml* is multilingual. Just check links from [this](http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2.2-final.html) page to see explanations.